# Want to get more than 1 value by using regex c#

Tags: c#

```
> String St = "New Specification Result :    Measures 0.0039mm ( 4 Microns )New Specification Result :    Measures 0.0047mm ( 5 Microns )";
```

The string that i want to get is `0.0039mm` and `0.0047mm` but the code i use keep giving me `0.0047mm` only.

```
 var src = st;
 var pattern = @"([0-9].[0-9]{4}mm)";
 var expr = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     foreach (Match match in expr.Matches(src))
     {
         string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
         string key2 = match.Groups[2].Value;
         label1.Text = key + key2;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the following.  Your loop is is overwriting your copy of the first result (and you don't have a 2nd capture group.  You have a 2nd *match*)

```
  var st = "New Specification Result :    Measures 0.0039mm(4 Microns)New Specification Result: Measures 0.0047mm(5 Microns";

  var pattern = @"([0-9]\.[0-9]{4}mm)";
  var expr = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  string key = "";
  foreach (Match match in expr.Matches(st))
  {
    key += match.Groups[1].Value;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, and the millimeter number you are trying to match is being captured correctly, but in the *first* capture group, and not in the second.  There is a slight problem with your pattern, and it should be this:

```
([0-9]\.[0-9]{4}mm)
```

You intend for the dot to be a literal decimal point, so it should be escaped with a backslash.  Here is the full code:

```
var pattern = @"([0-9].[0-9]{4}mm)";
var expr = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
foreach (Match match in expr.Matches(src))
{
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string key2 = match.Groups[2].Value;    // this doesn't match to anything here
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

you want to iterate through each match and the join them together for display

```
var mm = new Regex(@"([0-9]\.[0-9]{4}mm)").Matches(src).Select(m => m.Groups[1]).ToList();
var list = string.Join(" ", mm);
label1.Text = list;
```

currently you are only getting the last match as you keep overwriting the text in your label

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's his regex, and yes, and in this case makes no difference

Comment: You are right that it happens to make no difference here.